# the plugin "com.gradle.scan" is not working i ngradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

i want to implement test runner for a cucumber freature file which said i am missing the com.gradle.scan plugin which i am trying to add but amm getting a error

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
        id "com.gradle.scan" version"3.0"
    }

    group 'gradleSampleAC'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8


repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url "http://gscentral.area.services.gs.com/content/group/public"
        }

        maven {
            url "http://area.services.gs.com/area/repo/public"
        }
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2' }
    }

dependencies {
        testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.11.0"
        testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.11.0"
        testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
        testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:6.10.4"
        compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.1"
        compile "org.testng:testng:7.4.0"
        testImplementation "info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4"
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9'
        testCompile 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:0.15'
        implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-ie-driver', version: '4.1.1'
        compile "ru.yandex.qatools.ashot:ashot:1.5.4"
        testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.5.2'
        implementation group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports', version: '5.0.9'
        implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.0.0'


    }
apply plugin: 'com.gradle.build-scan'
```

This is what my build.gradle file looks like and this is the error that i get:

Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.scan', version: '3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle.scan:com.gradle.scan.gradle.plugin:3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Comment: Have you tried using their recommended configuration?
https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/gradle-plugin/